# Elasticsearch scoring and boosting query on match resultset

Tags: elasticsearch, match, scoring

I have below type documents in elasticsearch.I want to make a query like when query result will match with particular records then it will automatically set according to its weightage.

     `{
         "_id": 652,
         "name":"jason rock",
          "emails": [
            {
              "email_id": "angel@gmail.com",
              "em_id": "1228"
            },
            {
              "email_id": "rock@gmail.com",
              "em_id": "1228"
            }
          ],
          "org": [
            {
              "org_job_title": "Manager",
              "org_name": "OYO Rooms",
              "org_id":2
            },
            {
              "org_job_title": "QA Lead",
              "org_name": "prime technology",
              "org_id":1
            }
          ],
          "address": [
            {
              "add_id": "15067770698711",
              "formatted_address": "TUCSON AZ"
            },
            {
              "add_id": "15078034145004",
              "formatted_address": "DRAGRAM SUITE"
            }
         ]`
}

I want query when any match found with name then it show at top after emails.email_id then after org.org_name,org.org_job_title and then address.formatted_address should match.

if match not found with name then according to above mentioned priority will display.Example if record not match with name and email.email_id but match with org.org_name that record should be on top of result.

If records presents in  both,name for _id :102 and org.org_name for _ids:101 then _id:102 would appear at top.